# Eclipse + maven : profile ignored

Tags: maven, filtering, profile

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.heliosophiclabs</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <serverAddr>localhost</serverAddr>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <serverAddr>heliosophiclabs.com</serverAddr>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

I have a config.properties file in src/main/resources, which looks like this:

```
serverIp=${serverAddr}
```

and then I do:

```
mvn clean resources:resources -Pprod
```

Note that the profile is specified here as "prod", and yet, no matter how I insist, the config.properties file looks like this after the above command line:

```
serverIp=localhost
```

whereas it should be:

```
serverIp=heliosophiclabs.com
```

If I specify a non-existent profile in this command line, then maven gives me an error, so it's definitely doing something.

Please... what am I doing wrong here??

EDIT:

As requested, the output of "mvn -X -Pprod install" is available [here](http://heliosophiclabs.com/~mad/mvn.out), since it's far too big to post here.

And here is exactly what I see:

```
C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage>mvn -X -Pprod install > mvn.out
C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage>more target\classes\config.properties
serverAddr=localhost
```

In entourage-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, config.properties is at the root, and its contents are the same as above (i.e., localhost).

I'm not making stuff this up!

Comment: Your config.properties is inside src/main/resources wright? You are telling maven, that there is where your resources are. Alse you are telling maven that it should filter your resources (filtering=true), that is, any file inside resources that has a place holder (${some.property}) should be "filtered" with the values provided by your filters (you declare your filters in the filters section in the pom), pom properties or command line properties

Comment: Yes, config.properties is in src/main/resources, but now I'm very confused.  You said I should have only the `env` property defined in the pom (like http://heliosophiclabs.com/~mad/pom.xml.txt ) ... and now you're saying that I should have `serverAddr` defined as well?
I assuming all of this is a workaround for an inexplicable problem with the way I was doing it in the first place, which really should work fine.  Am I right, or was I doing it wrong before?

Comment: No! serverAddr should be in the filters not in the pom (in local.properties put serverAddr=localhost, in prod.properties put serverAddr=heliosophiclabs.com). You are doing it fine in the first place, this workaround is just to see if the profile is getting activated or not, if not, it should throw an error cause maven will not find ${env}.properties file to get the filters values (or value in this case: serverAddr). Filters are better when you have several values to replace (for keeping the pom clean), in your case, using properties in the pom is fine, but just for testing...

Comment: Not in the pom?  So, I need some other file?  I'm reading maven docs about filtering, but all I see is the initial way I tried (which failed).  Anyway, it does look as if the profile is correctly activated, based on the -X debug output.  I do `mvn -X process-resources -Pprod > mvn.out` ... the output is here: http://heliosophiclabs.com/~mad/mvn.out

As you can see, `[DEBUG] properties used { ... env=prod` and `[DEBUG]   (f) buildFilters = [C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage\filters\prod.properties]`

Comment: Instead of using properties in the profile, you can use a filter, and put those properties in there as `key=value`. In this case we need two filters, one for local, and one for prod, they will have only one property each (serverAddr), but with different values. Have you put `serverAddr=localhost` in local.properties and `serverAddr=heliosophiclabs.com` in prod.properties? Sorry my bad english?

Comment: The profile is activating properly as I can see `buildFilters = [C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage\filters\prod.properties]` and maven is in fact filtering your resources: `filtering C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage\src\main\resources\config.properties to C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage\target\classes\config.properties`. The content of `prod.properties` should be `serverAddr=heliosophiclabs.com` and the content of `config.properties` (inside src/main/resources) should be `serverIp=${serverAddr}`

Comment: Yes, I have two properties files under the filters dir (local.properties & prod.properties), just as you describe.  But where would the value of `${serverAddr}` be dereferenced from?  the `serverAddr` property is no longer defined in my pom.
Your English is awesome... better than my Spanish, anyway :)

Comment: The value will be dereferenced from the filter! the one you specified on filters section in your pom (local or prod depending on the profile activated). So your files should look like [this files](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c0757fbf66cd69df1d8b). If your config.properties would had more properties, you can put more values in your filters (so your pom doesn't grow to big)

Comment: May be [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-resources-based-on-values-from-a-properties-file.html) tutorial help you out, although you are very close to have it right!

Comment: Ah.... so maven actually interprets the .properties file!  Sorry, the light bulb just came on.  Ok, I now have exactly the configuration you explained.... but I'm sorry to report I get the same result as initially.  I.e., no matter what I put for the `-P` argument, the `activeByDefault` profile is used for filtering.  Latest mvn.out : http://heliosophiclabs.com/~mad/mvn.out

Comment: I still see `buildFilters = [C:\Users\Marc\workspace_mars_2\entourage\filters\prod.properties]`, So the profile "prod" is being activated. This is so rare. Are you using eclipse with the m2e plugin? Sometimes this plugin updates the files on refresh (I think) and uses the default profile. If this is the case, right click on your project (the one that has the pom), go to Properties -> Maven, and fill in the "Active Maven Profiles" field. If you are running maven from a windows console, then, I don't know what is happening!

Comment: I am using Eclipse with m2e, but I've been doing all this from the command line to eliminate confusion.  You've been superhumanly patient and helpful.  It's ok at this point just to shake your head, throw up your hands,  and vaguely blame Windows, like I did.  Unless you have any other ideas...

Comment: Just in case, close the project in eclipse (or close eclipse) run the command in a cmd... Please tell me that you are looking the file generated in target! :P I am using maven in windows and never had this issue. So, the problem is the same whereas using pom properties or filters...! And is that the file gets filtered with the default profile.. What happens if  you put the **activeByDefault** in the prod profile?

Comment: OMG OMG OMG!!!!
Somehow... closing Eclipse did the trick!  I think I'll become superstitious.  This is just too much.  I still blame Windows somehow.  
Well.  This has been fun, if not necessarily educational, since I still have no idea what is causing this issue.  And it's sad that I can't use Eclipse to do the maven compilation.  The great irony is that I just posted this : http://www.quora.com/Why-are-tools-like-Vim-and-Emacs-still-used-for-coding/answer/Greg-Kemnitz/comment/9061166?srid=nOBS

Comment: Yes, I'm serious.  No, I'm not joking.  See here:
http://heliosophiclabs.com/~mad/mvn%20insanity.PNG
I swear I don't make this stuff up.
You've been amazing.  I suggest you post this answer so I can accept it so you can at least get some rep out of all this effort.

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis as to what might be causing this?  I mean, the target dir is definitely completely deleted and rewritten, whether or not Eclipse is open.  Amazingly, it works fine if I have this project open in Luna.  Is Mars just this unstable??  I guess that'll teach me not to use the latest version of anything...

Comment: Do you agree that this behavior is bugworthy???
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462027

Comment: My hypothesis is that the m2e is updating the target on refresh using the default profile. Do you have the option "Refresh using native hooks or polling" checked in "General -> Workspace"?. I have Eclipse 4.4, will try to reproduce your problem. And don't worry about the rep!

Comment: I have absolutely reproduced your problem!! I have noticed something else: having Eclipse open, run in command line `mvn clean`, now go to eclipse... the target is there and with the files and all! Didn't maven erase the target? yes it had, but Eclipse is regenerating it. Unchecking "Refresh on access", and "Refresh using hooks..." doesn't fix the problem. If you set in eclipse "Active Maven Profiles" to prod, and run `mvn process-resources -P local` you'll see that eclipse replaces it with prod profile. I don't know if is a bug or a feature! :P definitely, I don't want that kind of feature.

Comment: Unchecking "Refresh using hooks..." or "Refresh on access" doesn't fix the problem as, at the end, you want to see the generated files in your IDE. If eclipse doesn't do a refresh, your files are fine, but at the moment you refresh the project in eclipse, they get changed. Unchecking "Build Automatically", does fix the problem, but you will wave to remember to do a "Build Project"  whenever you change a java file... is a trade off...

Comment: According to Fred Bricon in your bug report, it is a feature, you shouldn't be using `-P` with eclipse, you should use `Ctrl+Alt+P` to select the profile... :P Nice to know!

Comment: wow.  you really should be working for the Eclipse Foundation.  That is exactly what they suggested, and it works.
But... I would expect that using an Eclipse maven build config would work with or without this option checked.  It does not.  If I set the "profile" option to "prod" in Eclipse, I get the same erroneous behavior as from the command line when this option is checked.  THIS IS ALL WRONG!

Comment: I agree, with this "feature", you should decide beforehand, which profile you will be using... Not nice. Maybe you could switch to gradle! :P Although is not maven's fault...

Comment: Maybe you could answer your self for future reference (googlers). You can also edit your question to clarify that you are using Eclipse (the problem was eclipse and not maven). Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much discussion, it finally turned out that the issue was with the use of the  "refresh using native hooks or polling" option ( preferences > general > workspace >  refresh using native hooks ).  Unchecking this option resolves the problem.

Bug report filed with Eclipse Foundation.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462027