# Maven filtering resources

Tags: maven, filtering, profile

I am running a simple maven project (maven version 3.3.9) with profiles and filtering on resources. It seems like the filtering is done always on the default profile.

There is 2 configuration files in src/main/filters (default) : config-dev.properties and config-prod.properties which contains only one variable
application.env=development
application.env=production

And a resource file in src/main/resources (default) with this content :

```
We are working on ${application.env}
```

Command line used is 
    mvn clean resources:resources -Pprod

The expected output is

```
We are working on production
```

But the filtered resource file contains

```
We are working on development
```

Maven pom snippet looks like:

```
<build>
    <finalName>test-maven-module</finalName>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/config-${build.profile.id}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

and profiles configuration

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the post [Eclipse + maven : profile ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861267/eclipse-maven-profile-ignored)

The issue was with the use of the "refresh using native hooks or polling" option ( preferences > general > workspace > refresh using native hooks ). Unchecking this option resolves the problem.