# Spring Boot from Maven Profile in POM

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-profiles

I have a spring boot application that has dev and prod settings.  Following multiple instructions found during searches I have an application.properties file which has:

```
#-----------this will load the prod or dev according to the @activatedProperties@ value which is set from the pom when built
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

Then there are two files:

- application-dev.properties
- application.prod.properties

I then have a pom which has the spring-boot pom as a parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I then set the profiles up as follows:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If I then execute a build as follows:

```
mvn -DskipTests -Pprod clean compile package
```

After doing this the application.properties file shows:

```
#-----------this will load the prod or dev according to the environment
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Note that it did not use prod as requested but instead dev.  In fact it simply execute the activeByDefault profile not matter what I do.  Has anybody else seen this and have any ideas as to what is happening.  As you can imagine it is really annoying to have the deploy instructions say 'edit the POM file to move the activeByDefault property from the dev to prod profile'!

Comment: Don't... Please don't. This means you are rebuilding artifacts for different environments and basically are promoting untested files to a new environment. Just specify the profile to use when starting the application. Don't use maven profiles to set a spring profile (those are also quite different things!).

Comment: Then how do I make a war file to deploy to a tomcat server in prod and run a tomcat instance in my dev environment?  I can't tell tomcat which profile to use when it starts.

Comment: I'm also not sure about the testing; when you test you _must_ use a different application properties to point to test copies of your external resources or you will corrupt production.  You don't do it with a maven profile but it is the same thing - using a different application properties file for test/dev/prod.

Comment: Yes you can. You can include that in your server.xml or application specific Context.xml. For testing you can include @ActiveProfiles or just specifying as context or environment variable. I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Boot reference guide and Spring Reference Guide regarding profiles.

Comment: So I edit the tomcat instance to define the spring boot profile to use?  That doesn't really seem like a single click deploy?

Comment: I read the spring reference guide on profiles - what is the difference between using maven to specify the application properties file to use on a prod or using activeprofiles to specify the test application properties?

Comment: The context.xml can be included in your application. The spring.profiles.active property (as well as all other properties) can be supplied in various ways (as explained in earlier said reference guide). How to include the context.xml is explained in the tomcat guide.

Comment: You need to rebuild the artifact. If you deploy to dev, test, prod it means you have 3 artifacts (each for a different environment) which basically also means you are deploying an untested artifact (as you have tested dev, which is different from test and different from prod). Instead you want a single artifact that you promote to a different environment.

Comment: Sorry but respectfully I disagree with you; spring boot specifically provides tools to do what I am doing above.  If you use the spring boot parent pom it actually adds application.properties as filter resource in maven.  It's referenced in the spring boot maven plugin and there are countless references to the above method.

Comment: If you test against a test resource and then deploy against a prod it'll be different always.  For example if you have a service which sends an email to register something you can't be doing that in test to a monitored email; you have to send somewhere different.  When you dev you run spring boot as an app but deploy in tomcat.  However this is academic to the original question and thanks for your advice but, respectfully, I will pass on this occasion.

Comment: We can agree to disagree, nonetheless you have multiple artifacts which you are using untested. The fact that something is provided, doesn’t mean it is a good idea to use it or to do so.

Comment: The following is an example of a setenv.bat file:
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=dev" for dev tomcat and change according to Prod for prod tomcat, spring will automatically pic the right application-xxx.properties/yml file,  Link - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40520_01/integrator.311/integrator_install/src/cli_ldi_server_config.html

Comment: Thanks but I'm not keen to modify the tomcat install which is running multiple applications just to accommodate one item.  The core question is - why is the profile not picked up in the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Eclipse is getting in the way; as the build happens eclipse is reinforcing the default profile; this happens in :

Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200

If you close eclipse and run from the command line it works just fine.

If you use eclipse then unchecking the Refresh on access under Preferences -> General -> Workspace then it works.  The clue was from another stack overflow question : [Eclipse + maven : profile ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861267/eclipse-maven-profile-ignored)

Thanks to all who took the time to reply.